# What type of data is being provided and how to process it?

Tags: export, web-gis

I want to export parcells from a turkish website (https://parselsorgu.tkgm.gov.tr/) to process them in my local GIS. When I press the "download coordinates" (Koordinat İndir) button, I receive the following Code as a .txt-File.

Does anyone know what to do with it?

```json
{"features":[{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.898781148363,38.1855669644728],
[26.8994285437289,38.1859964317269], [26.9000039354568,38.1859064694251],
[26.9010039392387,38.1857232572525], [26.9012690777017,38.1857333077248],
[26.9012731740156,38.1856166417659], [26.9012110058787,38.1855364899834],
[26.9011349388055,38.185501837885], [26.9010680516963,38.1855017820137],
[26.9007990741717,38.1855850377185], [26.9006442104839,38.1855862081821],
[26.9004548142372,38.1855392374418], [26.9000826960222,38.1853828851481],
[26.8999238601713,38.1852878008305], [26.8998340747551,38.1851742783011],
[26.8997972310622,38.1850700885492], [26.8998100130861,38.1849407304368],
[26.8998269085579,38.1848777188441], [26.9002729578217,38.1843510843207],
[26.9002780253781,38.1843115084165], [26.9002480490889,38.1842283647995],
[26.9001662166635,38.1841742029176], [26.899843643976,38.1841339217827],
[26.8997710923002,38.1841998547587], [26.8990512722744,38.1839163973072],
[26.8982755238355,38.1841332090128], [26.8979222700417,38.1849633488482],
[26.898781148363,38.1855669644728]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"52",
"SayfaNo":"3034", "Alan":"33.477,00", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı", "Nitelik":"Tarla
ve zeytinlik ve iki adet dam", "CiltNo":"31", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"08b309a4",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}},{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.8990512722744,38.1839163973072],
[26.8985817635572,38.1837926636102], [26.8974294478833,38.183696806571],
[26.8972286608049,38.1837934785044], [26.8973362102739,38.1847641048107],
[26.8979222700417,38.1849633488482], [26.8982755238355,38.1841332090128],
[26.8990512722744,38.1839163973072]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"6",
"SayfaNo":"722", "Alan":"11.307,80", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı",
"Nitelik":"Zeytinlik", "CiltNo":"8", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"L17c08b2",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}},{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.8991827084846,38.1876652179091],
[26.8996731600329,38.1874286095343], [26.9000861050935,38.1871070695489],
[26.9004339154288,38.1868379053336], [26.9012031128299,38.1868440451617],
[26.9016159748456,38.1866643003341], [26.9019563206545,38.1863369276563],
[26.9022458639263,38.1859276208097], [26.9020132774123,38.1854685133188],
[26.9013951937572,38.1857380881326], [26.9012690777017,38.1857333077248],
[26.9012589630186,38.1857583062721], [26.9012388624208,38.1857507707412],
[26.9012123314015,38.1858033799686], [26.9011710296497,38.185820053869],
[26.9005802075696,38.1859741116182], [26.900460534239,38.1860249715834],
[26.8997456191625,38.1864051272385], [26.899709103142,38.1864182996266],
[26.8991126297621,38.1864856530474], [26.8989727637729,38.186538231804],
[26.8988808689356,38.1866040258917], [26.8988223644944,38.1866649080097],
[26.8987407675191,38.18682951961], [26.8987760276,38.1869843502522],
[26.8989312324186,38.187130192939], [26.8990701764607,38.1872045498448],
[26.8991028316748,38.1872497662475], [26.8991150260325,38.1873046484689],
[26.8990822308716,38.1873627200973], [26.898899350381,38.1875098028591],
[26.8987836585767,38.1876436068806], [26.8986727056471,38.1878315457941],
[26.8986173866517,38.1878096561133], [26.8982710645656,38.1884048830017],
[26.8982661880643,38.188590938838], [26.8984017744164,38.1887054951552],
[26.8984017744164,38.1887054951552], [26.8987745846863,38.1884654934941],
[26.8991827084846,38.1876652179091]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"51",
"SayfaNo":"3033", "Alan":"34.931,69", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı",
"Nitelik":"Zeytinlik", "CiltNo":"31", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"L17c09a4",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}},{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.9012123314015,38.1858033799686],
[26.9012388624208,38.1857507707412], [26.9012589630186,38.1857583062721],
[26.9012690777017,38.1857333077248], [26.9000039354568,38.1859064694251],
[26.8994285437289,38.1859964317269], [26.898781148363,38.1855669644728],
[26.89674253734,38.1869298772018], [26.8970094423775,38.1874788439418],
[26.8967169311072,38.187945071616], [26.8967927035093,38.1885354930709],
[26.8973823042881,38.1885880773654], [26.8977076013913,38.1887662853563],
[26.8978097305304,38.1890384433123], [26.8980798574132,38.1889127313567],
[26.8984507873735,38.1887521405743], [26.8984017744164,38.1887054951552],
[26.8982661880643,38.188590938838], [26.8982710645656,38.1884048830017],
[26.8986173866517,38.1878096561133], [26.8986727056471,38.1878315457941],
[26.8987836585767,38.1876436068806], [26.898899350381,38.1875098028591],
[26.8990822308716,38.1873627200973], [26.8991150260325,38.1873046484689],
[26.8991028316748,38.1872497662475], [26.8990701764607,38.1872045498448],
[26.8989312324186,38.187130192939], [26.8987760276,38.1869843502522],
[26.8987407675191,38.18682951961], [26.8988223644944,38.1866649080097],
[26.8988808689356,38.1866040258917], [26.8989727637729,38.186538231804],
[26.8991126297621,38.1864856530474], [26.899709103142,38.1864182996266],
[26.8997456191625,38.1864051272385], [26.900460534239,38.1860249715834],
[26.9005802075696,38.1859741116182], [26.9011710296497,38.185820053869],
[26.9012123314015,38.1858033799686]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"50",
"SayfaNo":"3032", "Alan":"54.916,11", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı",
"Nitelik":"Zeytinlik", "CiltNo":"31", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"L17c09a4",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}},{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.9021360828109,38.1833020551613],
[26.9020050629529,38.1826871766657], [26.9017104320075,38.1820296400527],
[26.901202889505,38.181415258184], [26.90101448405,38.1816507747793],
[26.9011233167035,38.1817681706874], [26.9010079927323,38.1819838940404],
[26.9007511099026,38.1824562723361], [26.9005002490066,38.1828889211454],
[26.9006077413549,38.1831044067937], [26.9005342989023,38.1831495962412],
[26.9000566903555,38.1834451146879], [26.8998043250461,38.1835981205969],
[26.8994562111487,38.1837452514005], [26.8991669029091,38.183867526675],
[26.8990512722744,38.1839163973072], [26.8997710923002,38.1841998547587],
[26.899843643976,38.1841339217827], [26.9001231031436,38.1839354874527],
[26.9001735971019,38.1838950956265], [26.9006313939896,38.1840189985494],
[26.90073304837,38.1842422071309], [26.900354712055,38.1847518784398],
[26.9002523767385,38.1852039302409], [26.9002352558908,38.1853277041132],
[26.9006378159435,38.1854217202838], [26.9011851259752,38.1852737368067],
[26.9007734343617,38.1846500097348], [26.9011802912303,38.1844283697675],
[26.90110357265,38.18409740738], [26.9010123165938,38.1836267041128],
[26.9016578408288,38.1835680532952],
[26.9021360828109,38.1833020551613]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"34",
"SayfaNo":"3002", "Alan":"38.032,22", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı", "Nitelik":"Tarla
ve zeytinlik ve iki adet dam", "CiltNo":"31", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"09-a4",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}},{"type":"Feature", "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":[[[[26.8990893250058,38.1827876996199],
[26.897790385254,38.1831724381218], [26.8974294478833,38.183696806571],
[26.8985817635572,38.1837926636102], [26.8990512722744,38.1839163973072],
[26.8991669029091,38.183867526675], [26.8991372184615,38.1837411640137],
[26.8991612428982,38.1836029354037], [26.8991966134382,38.1835048005006],
[26.8992786628522,38.1833764377588], [26.8993978654513,38.1832957086567],
[26.8990893250058,38.1827876996199]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"36",
"SayfaNo":"3012", "Alan":"12.722,39", "Mevkii":"Kavakçayı",
"Nitelik":"Zeytinlik", "CiltNo":"31", "Ada":"154", "Il":"İzmir",
"Ilce":"Seferihisar", "Pafta":"L17c08b3 09a4",
"Mahalle":"Beyler"}}],"type":"FeatureCollection", "crs":{"type":"name",
"properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's data in GeoJSON format. You can use it for example in the free GIS suite QGIS.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) file, You can view it by copy pasting the feature in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0). Save the file with the `.JSON` extension instead of the `.txt` and you should be able to use it.

[image: What it looks like in GeoJson.io]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it?